# Kickstart not installing with @^Graphical-server-

Tags: rhel, gui, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I am trying to use kickstart script to automate RHEL installation with GUI and developer environment, however anaconda would complain group package "graphical-server-environment" is missing and installation would fail.

```
%packages \
@^graphical-server-environment \
@base \
@core  \
@desktop-debugging \
@development-and-creative-workstation \
@dial-up \
@fonts \
@gnome-desktop \
@graphical-administration-tools \
@guest-agents \
@guest-desktop-agents \
@input-methods \
@internet-browser \
@multimedia \
@print-client \
@server-with-gui \
@x-window-system \
@x11
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Satellite as the package repository? I found a note regarding this, which is linked to a couple of bugs on Satellite: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5016571

Comment: @Haxiel I don't have license to access the URL, would you be able to explain the bug?

Comment: That's a little strange, because you need a Red Hat account to do pretty much anything with RHEL. Anyway, the bug is regarding the use of Satellite 6.6, which fails to correctly generate the repository definitions for environment groups. So when yum connects to that repo and tries to install an environment group, it is reported as missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the above instead :

```
@^Server with GUI
```